# Trouble Implementing Generic Tree

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, tree, directory

So I have created a class for my generic tree and the Node class that goes along with it. The classes are as follows:

```
public class DirectoryTree<E> implements Serializable {
    protected Node<E> root;
    protected Node<E> child;

    public DirectoryTree() {
        root = null;
    }//end constructor

    protected DirectoryTree(Node<E> root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return root.children == null;
    }

    public DirectoryTree<E> getTree() {
        if (root != null) {
            return new DirectoryTree<E>(root);
        }//end if
        else {
            return null;
        }//end else
    }


    public Node<E> getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public Node<E> getChild() {
        return child;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return null;

    }//end toString()


}

class Node<E> implements Serializable {
    protected Node<E> parent;
    protected E data;
    protected ArrayList<Node<E>> children;

    public Node(E data) {
        this.data = data;
        children = new ArrayList<Node<E>>();
    }

    public Node<E> getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public ArrayList<Node<E>> getChildren() {
        return this.children;
    }

    public int getNumberOfChildren() {
        return getChildren().size();
    }

    public boolean hasChildren() {
        return getChildren().size() > 0;
    }

    public void addChild(Node<E> child) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            if (child == children.get(i)) {
                System.out.println("directory exists");
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if (counter == 0) {
            children.add(child);
        } else {
        }
    }

    public E getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return data.toString();
    }


}
```

I am wondering whether my 2 classes are set up correctly for a generic tree.
Also, I am not sure how to even implement this tree into a program.  My program is supposed to be a program that creates directories and files and puts them in the tree.  My root directory must be named /.  So far my main class is (i just started it):

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Fake Unix");
        System.out.print("$");
        File f = new File("//");
        String input = in.nextLine();
        DirectoryTree tree = new DirectoryTree(new Node<File>(f));
        while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
            String[] command = input.split(" ");
            if (command[0].equals("mkdir") && command[1].equals("-p") && command.length == 3) {
                File f1 = new File(command[2]);
                tree.root.addChild(new Node<File>(f1));
                System.out.println("complete");
            }//end if

            if (input.equals("tree")) {
                System.out.println(tree.toString());
            }
            System.out.print("$");
            input = in.nextLine();
        }//end while

    }//end main
}//end class
```

So what I am basically asking is if my methods look correct within my tree and node classes and whether or not i am heading in the right direction implementing them in the main class.  Am i creating the directories correctly or is my syntax wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you attempted to run your `Driver` class and checked to see if directories are being created?

Comment: well im not getting any errors.  but how do i check if the directory is created? @Foxsly

Comment: See my answer below. You should be able to see the directories on your filesystem, at the location specified by `f1.getAbsolutePath()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the directories to be created on your filesystem. Some digging through the [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) javadocs indicates that you need to call [`file.mkdir()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir()) for each directory that you're adding.

As far as your classes go:

1. I don't see any use for the `protected Node<E> child` in `DirectoryTree`. You have the root, and if that's what the tree is going to hold, you can navigate to any children through that node.
2. You don't currently have a way to set the `protected Node<E> parent` in `Node`. If you ever need to navigate up the tree from a child element, that would be useful - you'd essentially need to implement a [Doubly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list)
3. You shouldn't be accessing the member variables of `Node` directly from the `DirectoryTree` (see the `isLeaf()` method). Use the getters on `Node`, like `Node#getChildren()`

Comment: I appreciate your feedback.  The thing i am confused about is how to so store the directories in the nodes.  file.mkdir() returns a boolean value to tell you whether the directory was created or not.  My question is, how do i store the directories in nodes in the main method?? @Foxsly

Comment: You already are. A `File` can represent either a file or a directory, so when you add the node to the tree (or add it as a child node of another node) it's represented in the tree.

Comment: so to add another child to the root i would basically just call tree.root.addChild(<Node>)?  What about if i wanna add a child to another rode other than the root?  Sorry if i sound ignorant I am just trying to understand trees better. @Foxsly